# Converting Stream to WMA

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, audio, stream

I am creating an application in Silverlight that needs to read its contents. I am using WCF service to send content to server side, then there is this code to synthesize text to speech.

```
public class SpeechService
{
  [OperationContract]
  public byte[] StartSpeak(string Text)
  {
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer synhesizer = new System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer())
    {
      synhesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(System.Speech.Synthesis.VoiceGender.NotSet, System.Speech.Synthesis.VoiceAge.NotSet, 0, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pl-PL"));
      synhesizer.SetOutputToWaveStream(ms);
      synhesizer.Speak(Text);
  }
  return ms.ToArray();
}
```

on the client side I use this code: http://elegantcode.com/2010/03/07/text-to-speech-in-silverlight-using-wcf/ to play created sound to client with MediaElement.

It works, but I need to tune it up because generated stream is quite large - 2 minute news is over 8MB. For last few days I was browsing the web for solution to two problems:
1. Streaming audio data to Silverlight with wcf
2. Compressing audio before sending it to the client

As for problem no. 1 I have no idea how to achieve it :/ I will use any help or ideas.
The most difficult thing with no. 2 is that I can not save output sound as a file. I need to do encoding on the fly and send compressed sound to client. For what I know the best idea is to encode is as AAC or WMA, as both of these are supported by MediaElement.

I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Seriously no one can help? :(

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking at Windows Azure Media Services. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/media-services/

It offers 'live streaming' which you could likely use with your audio. I've worked with this for on-demand, but not live, streaming, and it's really easy to do. Just upload your media 'to the cloud', and it will encode and give you an endpoint. You can then consume this endpoint within a Silverlight Media Element to get the streamed media.